# How to stub a function that responds with an HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, sinon

I am using ExpressJS and want to stub a function that responds with an HTTP response as a part of a router. In particular, it is a request to Amazon S3 that I am trying to stub.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', (err, url) => {
    res.json({ url: url });
  });
};
```

I am trying to stub `getSignedUrl` using `sinon`.

```
sinon.stubs(s3, 'getSignedUrl').returns({})
```

How can I properly stub this method? I don't want to make the request to S3 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stub this, because `getSignedUrl` doesn't actually make a request to S3.

Signed URLs are generated entirely locally... a canonical version of the request that will accompany the URL is signed using a hashed message authentication code (HMAC) algorithm that produces a signature that the service can use, later, to validate that the request signature was created with valid credentials (yet the signarure is computationally-infeasible to reverse-engineer.)

You can illustrate this to yourself in a couple of ways: generate signed URLs for the same object and parameters, in a loop, and you'll notice that they only actually change as your system clock ticks forward each second.  Set your clock back a few seconds, and the cycle of generated URLs will repeat itself with identical values based on the time on *your* system clock.  Or, generate signed URLs for nonexistent objects or buckets... the generation is local, so no error occurs.  Or make up a fake access-key-id and secret.  You can generate signed URLs all day.  They won't actually be valid if you try to use them, but they can still be generated without error.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good to me. This here should work:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const s3 = require('s3');
sinon.stub(s3, 'getSignedUrl', params => {
  return Promise.resolve('http://dummy-url.com/signed');
});

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject');
console.log(url);
```

And you don't get `TypeError: stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed, see documentation`
 in the console ? Then you would need to change the syntax.

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/